# Sharepoint list : Formatting for lookup column to see future dates only

Tags: sharepoint-server, lookup-column, sharepoint-list

I have two lists (1) Meeting schedule and (2) meeting Agenda. the 2nd list (meeting agenda) has look up column which linked to meeting schedule.
**Question: Is there a way where only future dates from the meeting schedule is displayed in 2nd list?**

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, after creating a lookup column in the meeting Agenda list, you could set a filter in the view to show future dates.

Comment: But my problem is not about view. it is about the drop down given to the user based on the values put in first list. 
for example : if the first list 'meeting schedule' has dates like 10 May 2020, 12 June 2020, 12 July 2020, 15 Aug 2020, 20 Sept 2020, at present all these dates are available in drop down in 2nd list. 
what I want is to show only the future dates in 2nd list (which is linked to first list as loop up column)